# Trace of a function

Tags: trace, trace-map

A very simple question which I cannot seem to find an answer for... given a function $u$ defined on some open subset $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$, is it customary to omit writing the trace operator $T$ and write $u=f$ on $\partial\Omega$ for some function $f$ when we mean $Tu=f$ on $\partial\Omega$?